# Secure Message Communication Java

Tags: java, security, encryption, hash, rsa

So, I am attempting to provide a secure application message communication system that provides all benefits of CIA.

I have a sender and a recipient.

Sender Keys:
Private = (55,27)
Public = (55,3)

Receiver Keys:
Private = (35, 29)
Public = (35,29)

In this particular scenario, I am utilizing RSA, a Digital Signature, And a shift cipher.

However, for some reason when implementing this into code, i'm getting stuck.

For my particular case:

I have the message string "CIS"

After deciding on a Ks (5)

I shift all the letters by the designated Ks using the ShiftCipher, and I get the message "hnx" which, after converting to a bigInteger using ASCII, I get 204210220. (This is after adding 100 to every value to get 3 digits for each letter.)

So here is where I get lost during the step by step process.

To my understanding. I first hash the message. So upon deciding upon a hash of 6, (204210220 % 6) I get 4.

So then, I encrypt the hashed message. Which would be Ka-(H(m)) or otherwise 4^26 mod 55. Which gets me 49.

I am suppose to integrate this using a digital signature. Which would be

47^27 mod 55. Which gets me the answer 53.

Next, I would Ks with Bob's public key, so 5^29 mod 35, which gets me 10.

After this, I'm confused on what to do.

To my knowledge, I'm suppose to encrypt the 53 a key, but I'm confused as to which.

In addition to this, after finally sending all this to the receiver, how are they suppose to get the message since hashing is a one-way function?

I have this all implemented in code across multiple different classes that pass values back and forth, so I thought it would be easier to just type out my logic, so apologies!

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is this just for fun or is this something that will evolve into an actual implementation?  The first thing I notice is that none of this is remotely secure for a magnitude of reasons - you understand this, yes?

Comment: This is just for basic understanding and it's implementation is merely for clarity and learning.

Comment: Okay.  Well first - your RSA key sizes are far, far too small.  You're also using RSA without padding which, by definition, isn't secure.  Also, you need to decide if you want to *encrypt* the message or *sign* the message.  These are two different things and serve two different purposes.  If you're encrypting, you shouldn't hash, you encrypt the message with the **public key**.  If you're signing, you encrypt the hash of the message with the **private key**.  These are all basic concepts.  I highly suggest you research this yourself - there is plenty of information available.

Comment: What i've been taught at least, the hash is already known by both parties. So what would be the use of encrypting the hash with the private key?

Comment: The private key owner creates a message, hashes it, and encrypts the hash with their private key.  The message, and the encrypted hash, are sent to the recipient, who has the corresponding public key.  This person can then decrypt the hash with the public key, compute the hash themselves, and compare them to ensure that the message did actually come from the person who owns the private key.